# Django how can i find_all book by сategory = None

Tags: python, django

How can i take all books when i pass None, cuz in Ruby if i write something like that

```
Book.where(category = None) => Give all Books
```

I try this

```
Book.objects.filter(category = None) => empty QuerySet
```

In general, there is some method in django that covers this logic

Comment: you're doing it correct. Any Errors or empty response?

Comment: @HemalPatel but i need Book.objects.filter(category = None) => QuerySet[With all books]

Comment: If you need all the records from the Book model, use Book.objects.all()

Comment: @DarshilJani yes i know, but in my specific logic i need to Book.filter(category = None) => All books.

Comment: The syntax will change based on the programming language that you're using. As you're using Django, Book.objects.all() would get you all the objects from Book model, whereas Book.objects.filter(category=None) will get you all the objects from Book model which do not have a category assigned to them. Please explain your required condition a bit more in case I have misunderstood your question.

Comment: @DarshilJani in ruby we have Book.all == Book.objects.all. But ruby covers the logic when we search by none example ( Book.where(category = nil) => ruby understand this and return all Books => Book.all). But django don't covers this, or i dont know some method for do this. Question we have method which cover this or i need create custom method?. I dont need Book.objects.all.

Comment: actually i dont understand what exactly you want to fetch you want `None or Not None or All` ?

Comment: @HemalPatel I want fetch all books when i use Book.objects.filter(Category = None)

Comment: you cant ask for All the Books and filter with None Category

Comment: @Smile1 and why would you need that? Note that you can _chain_ queryset methods: `books = Book.objects.all()` and then `books.filter(category="PQR")` and so on, I don't really understand your use case here of needing to pass in a `None` and getting all objects...

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat you don't need to understand why I want to use it, I just asked if I can do it in django

Comment: Looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. The answer to your X problem is no, there's no such builtin method. The Y problem is unknown to us so we can't answer that.

Answer (score 0):

For Books with None category:

```
Book.objects.filter(category = None)
```

All the books:

```
Book.objects.all()
```

For Books with NOT NONE category:

```
Book.objects.all().exclude(category=None)
```

This is the way for `Python/Django` if you want to filter with whatever your requirement.

Comment: thanks, but all these methods I know, I just asked if I can do my specific logic in django

Comment: @Smile1 no you cant.

Comment: Thanks, that's all I wanted to hear.